# Convergence of series with terms from a different convergent series with postive terms.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{ a_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n > 0$. Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. Do the following series converge?

(a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$

(b) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+k^2a_n}$

(c) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n}$

### My Attempt

Since we are only given that $a_n > 0$, we cannot assume that the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is monotone. So the tests for convergence that require the monotonicity condition cannot be applied.

(a) Clearly $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \leq a_n$ for all $n$. So by the [Direct Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test), $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

(b) Let $b_n = \frac{a_n}{1+k^2a_n}$. Since $a_n > 0$, it follows that $b_n > 0$. Moreover, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, by the [Term Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$. Then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{a_n}{1}\cdot\frac{1+k^2a_n}{a_n}] = \lim_{n\to\infty} [1 + k^2 a_n] = 1 + k^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$$

So by the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+k^2a_n}$ converges for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

(c) Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, by the Term Test we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$. That is,

$$a_n \to 0 \quad\text{as}\quad n \to \infty.$$

It follows that,

$$ \sin(a_n) \to 0 \quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty  $$

Then $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n} = \frac{0}{0}$. So the limit does not exist? Thus by the Term Test the series diverges.

### Questions

I do not see a test of convergence that I can apply to (c).

**Edit**: The series in (c) should diverge. If we let $a_n = 1/n^2 >0$, then the series $\sum 1/n^2$ converges by the p-series. Now $\sum \sin(1/n^2)/(1/n^2) = \sum n^2 \sin(1/n^2)$ diverges since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \sin(1/n^2) = 1 \neq 0.$$

Granted this counter example works, can I choose $\{ a_n \}$ to be such a sequence? Is it possible that there exists another sequence $\{ a_n \}$ for which the series in (c) converges?

**Edit 2**: As pointed out in the comments, $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n} \neq \frac{0}{0}$ but instead $1$. So by the Term Test, since the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n} = 1 \neq 0$, the series in (c) should diverge.

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)} x$ isn't $\frac00$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Ah, I should have doubled checked my work. Thank you, I think I have a solution now combined with the other comments.

Answer (score 1):

About c). Let $a_n=1/n^2$. then for $n\gg1$ $\sin a_n\sim a_n$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin a_n/a_n=1$ and the series diverges.

Comment: Except this works for any $a_n$ that converges to $0$.  You don't need to pick that specific example.

Comment: Why is it "except"?

Comment: You want $ \sum a_n$ to converge. That is the only necessary assumption.

Comment: Excellent. I just actually came up with this example messing about on WolframAlpha. But I'll try to figure out a general way.

Comment: The question asks how to prove c) in general. The answer shows that c) s not always true. Ant other objections?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above c) is never true if the original series converges.